# How to use the java debug flag to look up parameters during compilation

Tags: java, spring, debugging

I'm a noob and I was reading the spring reference documentation, specifically the section: [constructor argument resolution](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution)

The documentation has a snippet in regards to dependency injection and defining your `constructor-arg` bean `name`:

```
package examples;

    public class ExampleBean {

        // Number of years to calculate the Ultimate Answer
        private int years;

        // The Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything
        private String ultimateAnswer;

        public ExampleBean(int years, String ultimateAnswer) {
            this.years = years;
            this.ultimateAnswer = ultimateAnswer;
        }

    }
```

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
    <constructor-arg name="years" value="7500000"/>
    <constructor-arg name="ultimateAnswer" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

**Keep in mind that to make this work out of the box your code must be compiled with the debug flag enabled so that Spring can look up the parameter name from the constructor. If you can’t compile your code with debug flag (or don’t want to) you can use @ConstructorProperties JDK annotation to explicitly name your constructor arguments.**

I'm trying to understand how the compiler actually works and maybe a simple explanation.  For example:

1. How do the parameters become available during compile time if debug mode is enabled?  Does the compiler like put parameters in a special place in memory that spring can then access, or how does the process of obtaining parameters actually work?
2. Presumably debug mode enables this mechanism to obtain parameters based on [ConstructorProperties.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html) i.e. `Since parameter names are not in general available at runtime`

But since they say "in general" makes me think sometimes they are available? Just looking for someone to explain this in a way that I might understand.

Comment: Can someone first explain me this statement `your code must be compiled with the debug flag enabled `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters names are not useful at runtime, unless you need them for some kind of reflection based binding (like spring does), but are useful during debugging, because you possibly want to inspect variables by name.

So, adding debugging information add those metadata to the class file. How springs achieve that is beyond my knowledge, but I think it might be based on bytecode tools (like ASM).

Spring uses bytecode manipulation tool to do some special injections.

Saying that *in general* this is so means that it depends on both the compiler and the runtime used. Since java 8 there is the -parameters flag to add params names to the class metadata.

I can also imagine that different compilers or pre/post compile processor could in fact add such information to the class files, but since the compiler spec do not require to do so they are *in general* not available.

Comment: thanks I've accepted your answer.  Although anyone who looks at this I highly recommend to look at https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/09/springone2gx-2014-replay-living-in-the-matrix-with-bytecode-manipulation.  It provides a low level overview of dependency injection in the spring framework (among others such as hibernate).  But your answer steered me in the right direction for google searches :)